# Do Neutral Jungle creeps get stronger as time goes on?

Tags: dota-2

I know lane creeps get stronger, and Rosh, but what about jungle neutrals?

Comment: this can be easily tested, and the answer is no.

Comment: True, but the question and the answer should be on the site :D

Comment: Well if that's the case, I think rules suggest this kind of question belongs to community wiki. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Jungle creeps stay at the same amount of toughness throughout the game.